# XML only partially downloading on Android with Groovy

Tags: android, groovy, xml-parsing

I've been going through the "Learn Android Lolipop Development" course by Tim Buchalka on Udemy. He teaches the class in Java, but I thought it would be a good learning experience to do it in groovy instead. That being said, I've come to a point where he is creating an app that downloads the Top 10 Free Apps XML from [Apple's Website](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml)

The part of the app that I've written that downloads the XML is:

```
public class XMLDownloader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
String myXMLData

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... urls) {
    try {
        myXMLData = downloadXML((String) urls[0])
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return "Unable to download XML file"
    }
    return ""
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("OnPostExecute", myXMLData)
}

String downloadXML(String url) throws IOException {

    String xmlContents = ""

    BufferedReader reader

    try {
        reader = new URL(url).openStream().newReader()

        while (reader.any()) {
            xmlContents += "${reader.readLine()}\n"
        }

        return xmlContents;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    } finally {
        reader?.close()
    }

}
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be downloading the full XML.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("OnPostExecute", myXMLData)
}
```

is only printing out the first 31 lines. Having only the first 31 lines downloaded is making parsing the XML impossible.

Using XmlPullParser to parse, I get

> 06-22 14:58:17.245  30926-30926/com.lategame.top10downloader W/System.err﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: /entry read: summary (position:END_TAG @17:54 in java.io.StringReader@158cb17f)

What could be causing the XML to only partially download?

Also, disregard the fact that I'm using `AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>` and casting to a `String`, instead of using `AyncTask<String, Void, String>`. That was a workaround to a whole other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the culprit was logcat having a max length for logs.
It was downloading the full XML, I just couldn't log it all out.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite downloadXml as

```
String downloadXML(String url) {
    new URL(url).text
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot simpler. It does work better, but it's still only printing 41 lines. Does logcat have a max length that it will print out in one message?

Comment: Try logging out the `length()` of the string?

Comment: You could also try just calling `new XmlSlurper().parse(url)`, as that should handle the streaming for you and return a [GPathResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Comment: For whatever reason, Android Studio can't find XMLSlurper to import it and it doesn't show up in groovy.util. Do I need to add something to dependencies to get it?

Comment: Should just be automatically imported in groovy.util

Comment: Like this. http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid.html but xmlslurper in place of jsonslurper